# Iterating n python iterators at once

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to iterate a bunch of data ranges at once, to get the combinations of all their values.

The number of ranges can differ, but I have them collected in a list.

Is there a way to iterate them using list comprehension or a similar clean, pythonic way?

This is what I mean by iterating together:

```
[print(i, j) for i in r1 for j in r2]
```

So that's a simple example with two known ranges, but what I need is more like

```
[print(i, j, ...) for i in r1 for j in r2 for k in r3...]
```

Note: i don't just need a list of number combinations, the iterators are my own iterator class which works similarly to `range()` but allows me to also get current state without calling `next()`, which would alter the state.

My iterator class sets its value back to the start on StopIteration, so it can be looped through more than once.

Here you can see the class:

```
@dataclass
class Range:
    start: float
    end: float
    step: float = field(default=1)
    includeEnd: bool = field(default=True)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.value = self.start
        
    def __next__(self):
        v = self.value
        end = v > self.end if self.includeEnd else v >= self.end
        if not end:
            self.value += self.step
            return v
        else:
            self.value = self.start
            raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: You're looking for `itertools.product()`.

Comment: If "r2" is an iterator (but not an iterable) it will be exhausted after the first "i" (outer for-iteration) and won't produce anything for the next "i".

Comment: @Julien I didn't see where he said combinations, I thought he wanted parallel.

Comment: As an aside, `range` is not an iterator.

Comment: "My iterator class sets its value back to the start on StopIteration, so it can be looped through more than once." **don't do that**. That *violates the iterator protocl*. Why would you do that? Seriously, *why not just use `range` objects*? They *aren't* iterators, so you *can* iterate over them multiple times.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can't use range() cause I need to be able to read the current value in another code snippet without modifying it, which is impossibile since the only way to read from a range is using next() afaik

Comment: Well you should *still implement the descriptor protocol correctly*. And no, **you can't use `next` on a `range` object at all, unless you want a TypeError**

Comment: You still want `itertools.product()` ;-) It doesn't care whether your pass it iterators or iterables. It materializes each argument's sequence once at the start, into internal tuples, then iterates as many times as needed across those internal tuples.

Comment: But how would you get the product of n iterators using `itertools.product()`, when you have a list of n iterators?

Comment: Sorry,  comments don't support formatted code - so I added an answer instead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how would you get the product of n iterators using itertools.product(), when you have a list of n iterators?

`itertools.product(*the_list)`. Nothing special about `product()` there. The leading `*` is general Python syntax for treating a list (more generally, an iterable) as a sequence of individual arguments.

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> args = [range(2), range(3), (i**2 for i in [5, 9])]
>>> args
[range(0, 2), range(0, 3), <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001E2E7A710B0>]
>>> for x in product(*args):
...     print(x)
    
(0, 0, 25)
(0, 0, 81)
(0, 1, 25)
(0, 1, 81)
(0, 2, 25)
(0, 2, 81)
(1, 0, 25)
(1, 0, 81)
(1, 1, 25)
(1, 1, 81)
(1, 2, 25)
(1, 2, 81)
```

Comment: This almost works, the only problem is that itertools.product seems to iterate on a copy of my iterator objects, whereas I'd like the objects themselves to have their current value modified. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Temp solution: assigning the values back to the ranges as I iterate. https://pastebin.com/winMNr6x

Comment: No, as already said in a comment, `product()` deliberately constructs temporary tuples at the start and iterates over _them_ thereafter. There is no support anywhere in Python for distinguishing between iterables that can, and cannot, be restarted. As in the example I gave, generator expressions cannot be - they're forever dead after iterating over them once. That's why `product()` iterates over each argument only once at the very start, and iterates over those copies instad.

Comment: BTW, you can get at the internal tuples `product()` uses, and the current index into each, by calling `.__reduce__()` on the iterator `product()` returns. But that's an internal implementation detail (used for pickling), so you would use it at your own risk. In practice, though, the `__reduce__()` implementation here is unlikely to change.